# Differences between value=" {{ var }} " and [value]="var" in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-directives

Could someone explain to me what is the difference between

```
value="{{var}}" vs [value]="var"
```

Thanks.

Comment: The first seems similar to the string templating in angular where var would be the value that get's replaced between the curly brackets, the second seems strange, at most I could see it as a named property of an object during declaration, however, a bit more context could do wonders ;)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#a-new-mental-model

Comment: When I use the first one I have some problems in my code. ngSelected does not work properly . So I wanted to see a explanation how both works on back end. Thanks anyway

Comment: @cartant thanks, that's perfect for a context ::)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#a-new-mental-model

the 2 bracket types represent 2 different directions of data flow.

[target]="expression" is said aloud as 'bind target' and (target)="statement" as 'on target'

bind target, binds your JavaScript model to your view.

on target, raises an event, on change of the view, to your JavaScript model.

you can combine them to create bind-on target, which does both.

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation

value="{{var}}" is an interpolated binding. It can be used in the same manner as [attr.value]="var"

With these minor differences.

value="{{var}}" or using {{}} inside the content of html nodes, will only work on Strings.

The fact that {{ }} exists in angular means they need to do more work processing templates, but since this work is already sunk, you can feel free to use {{ }} where it makes more sense and improves readability without much of a performance hit.

If you need to bind to a non-string property, you will need to use the property binding syntax instead.

I'd recommend sticking to the property binding syntax `[value] = "var"` as it will allow you to use the 2 different directional bindings without too much mental overhead.

Comment: Sorry about the multitude of edits. My angular is a little rusty, so I was verifying information as I went.